# win check function isn't working properly in connect four programmed in c;

Tags: c

Hey guys so i'm just starting to learn c and my teacher gave me an assignment to create a version of connect four; everything works great exept for the wincheck for the bottom left with player one , the code is identical but for some reason it wont recognize a bottom left diaganol for player one and i cnat figure out why here is what i got so far (note that some functions were given to me by the teacher himself so their definition is kind of lacking):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include "stdio.h"
#include<stdbool.h>
#include "stdlib.h"
#define MAXturns 42
#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 7
char board[ROWS][COLS];

void printboard();


char playerswap(int i);

int inputprint(int colp, char apropriate);

int wincheck(int row, int col);

void initBoard();

char getCell(int row, int col);

void setCell(int row, int col, char sign);

void clearScreen();
int main()
{
    int i, col = 0,clonerow=0;
    initBoard();
    printboard();
    printf("\n");
    for ( i = 0; i <=MAXturns ; i++)  
    {
        if (i==MAXturns)
        {
            printf("it's a tie try again\n");
            system("pause");
            clearScreen();
            initBoard();
            printboard();
            i = 0;
        }
        if (playerswap(i) == 'X') 
        {
            printf("\nPlayer1:\nPlease enter a column number between 1-7:\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nPlayer2:\nPlease enter a column number between 1-7:\n");
        }
        scanf("%d", &col);
        if (col > 0 && col <= COLS)
        {
            if (getCell(1, col) != ' ')
            {
                printf("no room please try another column.\n");
                i--;
            }
            else
            {
                clonerow=inputprint(col, playerswap(i));
                clearScreen();
                printboard();
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("non applicable input\n");
            i--;
        }
        if (wincheck(clonerow,col)==1)
        {
            printf("\nplayer 1 you'r the winner!!!!\n");
            system("pause");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if (wincheck(clonerow,col)==2)
            {
                printf("\nplayer 2 you'r the winner!!!!\n");
                system("pause");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

char getCell(int row, int col)
{
    return board[row - 1][col - 1];
}

void setCell(int row, int col, char sign)
{
    board[row - 1][col - 1] = sign;
}

void initBoard()
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            setCell(i + 1, j + 1, ' ');
        }
    }
}

void clearScreen()
{
    system("cls");
}
    void printboard()
{
        int i, j, y_col = 1;
        for (i = 0; i <= ROWS; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                for (j = 1; j <= COLS; j++)
                    printf("  %d", j);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n");
                printf("%c", i+64);
                for (y_col = 1; y_col <= COLS; y_col++)
                {
                    if (y_col == 1)
                    {
                        printf(" %c", getCell(i, y_col));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    printf("  %c", getCell(i, y_col));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    int wincheck(int row,int col)
    {
        int i = 1, j = 1;
        for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            if (getCell(row, i) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 1) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 2) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 3) == 'X')
            {
            return 1;
            }
            else
            {
            if (getCell(row, i) == 'O' && getCell(row, i + 1) == 'O' && getCell(row, i + 2) == 'O' && getCell(row, i + 3) == 'O')
                {
                return 2;
                }
            }
        }
        if (row <= 3)
        {
            for (j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
            {
                if (getCell(j, col) == 'O' && getCell(j + 1, col) == 'O' && getCell(j + 2, col) == 'O' && getCell(j + 3, col) == 'O')
                {
                return 2;
                }
                if (getCell(j, col) == 'X' && getCell(j + 1, col) == 'X' && getCell(j + 2, col) == 'X' && getCell(j + 3, col) == 'X')
                {
                return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        if (getCell(row,col)=='X'&&getCell(row-1,col-1)=='X'&&getCell(row-2,col-2)=='X'&&getCell(row-3,col-3)=='X')
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (getCell(row, col) == 'X' && getCell(row - 1, col + 1) == 'X' && getCell(row - 2, col + 2) == 'X' && getCell(row - 3, col + 3) == 'X')\\this is the part that doesn't work for some reason 
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (getCell(row, col) == 'X' && getCell(row+1, col - 1) == 'X' && getCell(row+2, col - 2) == 'X' && getCell(row+3, col - 3) == 'X')
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (getCell(row, col) == 'O' && getCell(row+1, col + 1) == 'O' && getCell(row+2, col + 2) == 'O' && getCell(row+3, col + 3) == 'O')
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (getCell(row, col) == 'O' && getCell(row - 1, col - 1) == 'O' && getCell(row - 2, col - 2) == 'O' && getCell(row - 3, col - 3) == 'O')
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (getCell(row, col) == 'O' && getCell(row - 1, col + 1) == 'O' && getCell(row - 2, col + 2) == 'O' && getCell(row - 3, col + 3) == 'O')
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (getCell(row, col) == 'O' && getCell(row + 1, col - 1) == 'O' && getCell(row + 2, col - 2) == 'O' && getCell(row + 3, col - 3) == 'O')
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (getCell(row, col) == 'O' && getCell(row + 1, col + 1) == 'O' && getCell(row + 2, col + 2) == 'O' && getCell(row + 3, col + 3) == 'O')
        {
            return 2;
        }
    }

    int inputprint(int colp, char apropriate) {
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i <= ROWS; i++)
        {
            if (getCell(i, colp) != ' ')
            {
                setCell(i - 1, colp, apropriate);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == ROWS)
                    setCell(i, colp, apropriate);
            }
        }
        return i-1;
    }
    char playerswap(int i)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            return 'X';
        else
            return 'O';
    }
---
```

Comment: Edit your code, put an obnoxious ugly (easy to see) comment in the code showing where the problem occurs.  (if it's already there, I did not find it. :)

Comment: My bad, I must have copied wrong.  The code is complete. (embarrassed).

Comment: Hey sorry for the inconvenience I edited the code to the exact line were the problem is

Comment: Still do not see it.  About what line, or what word can I search for?

Comment: This is the line that doesn't work basically:if (getCell(row, col) == 'X' && getCell(row - 1, col + 1) == 'X' && getCell(row - 2, col + 2) == 'X' && getCell(row - 3, col + 3) == 'X')\\this is the part that doesn't work for some reason 
        {
            return 1;
        }

Comment: In the expression:  `getCell(row - 3, col + 3)`, What would happen if `row  <  3`?  Can that happen in your code?

Answer (score 1):

One apparent problem is that this code seems to be more liberal in its array indexing than the C language allows for.
C uses [zero based indexing for arrays](https://developerinsider.co/why-does-the-indexing-of-array-start-with-zero-in-c/).  For example, an array such as this:

```
int array[10]; //has room for 10 integer values, accessed like this:

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    array[i] = i;  //populates array[0] through array[9]
}
```

eg. For:

```
#define ROWS 6
#define COLS 7
char board[ROWS][COLS];

 ...

    for (i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        if (getCell(row, i) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 1) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 2) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 3) == 'X')
```

Array indexing should really be:

```
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {     
        if (getCell(row, i) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 1) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 2) == 'X' && getCell(row, i + 3) == 'X')
```

In this section `row - 3` will at some point be a negative value, resulting in a negative array index, which might be the problem you were seeing:

```
   if (getCell(row, col) == 'X' && getCell(row - 1, col + 1) == 'X' && getCell(row - 2, col + 2) == 'X' && getCell(row - 3, col + 3) == 'X')
    {
        return 1;
    }
```